# Submitting variables in POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a form that sends stuff like names and email and a message and I get it with `$_POST['etc'];` - But, I also want to send action=someaction as a part of the url, but I don't want to have any hidden form fields.

Can this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, just add it to your url: `<form action="url.php?action=someaction" method="post">`. You can retrieve them in your php script using `$_GET` (in this case, `$_GET['action']`).

Comment: Ah! So on my form code, I just write **<form action="contact.php?action=someaction" method="post">...</form>** ?

Comment: Exactly. You querystring parameters will be in `$_GET` and your form parameters will be in `$_POST`. And, as @eckes mentioned, both will be in `$_REQUEST`, but it is considered less "clean" to use that (citation needed).

Answer (score 1):

`action=someaction` cannot be read by `$_POST['whatever']` because it's submitted in a GET-Request. You can access GET and POST variables by using `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

To form the request, follow the answer of [Spiny Norman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554602/submitting-variables-in-post/4554620#4554620).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you simply need to add ?action=someaction to the action attribute of your form tag. These would be fetched from PHP by using $_GET instead of $_POST.

Example:

```
<form action="http://example.com?action=someaction">...</form>
```

and to get the value:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
```